# The 'gems' configuration option has been renamed to 'plugins'.?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

When I use the latest `jekyll` and start its server, a certain warning below shows up:

> $ jekyll serve Configuration file:
>   /Users/ishida/git/gipcompany.github.io/_config.yml
>          Deprecation: The 'gems' configuration option has been renamed to 'plugins'. Please update your config file accordingly.

I guess the following `gems` should be replaced with `plugins`, and then the warning won't show up, but I couldn't find any official documentation. Is my guess correct?

```
$ cat _config.yml
(omit)
gems:
  - jekyll-feed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your guess is correct, `gems` key is now `plugins`.

In `jekyll/lib/jekyll/configuration.rb` you can find:

```
def backwards_compatibilize
   ...
   renamed_key "gems", "plugins", config
```

It is part of  [this Pull Request](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/5130): **plugins config key as replacement for gems (#5130)**

And it was the result of this [issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4509):

> What do you think about renaming the gems config directive to plugins,
>   with full backwards compatibility?
>
> The idea being, if you're not from the Ruby world, "gems" isn't a very
>   intuitive term (even though that's what they are). Further, users
>   shouldn't have to care about (or see) the behind-the-scenes plumbing,
>   in terms of how things are distributed.
>
> Instead, let's call the key "plugins", a term which has a broader
>   understanding outside the Ruby ecosystem, and one that should be
>   familiar to any user coming from a more traditional CMS like WordPress
>   or Drupal.
>
> In terms of practicality, it'd just be a matter of combining the gems
>   and plugins arrays, if they exist when we load the config, and
>   updating the docs in the next minor release.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, in order to fix that, follow these steps:

1. Open your `_config.yml` file
2. Find the line beginning with `gems:`
3. Replace `gems` with `plugins`